# pentaho cde table component select diferent datasources

Tags: javascript, pentaho, pentaho-cde

Good afternoon,
I have a table in pentaho cde. I want to know if there is any way of depending on a value of a parameter ($ {Author}), I want to be able to choose one query or another. That is, I have a parameter ($ {Author}) that can have the value ' All' or many other values. I have a query with the name 'PrincipalSql' and another 'SecundariaSql'. I want to know if there is a pentaho form of if $ {Author} = 'All' then sqlqueri = 'PrincipalSql' else sqlQuery = 'SecondarySql'. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can change that in the preExec method of the table component. It’s called before the component executes.

Just test the param value and change the component’s chartDefinition.dataAccessId property.

Open the preExecution code editor (from advanced properties), and type something like this:

```
function(){
    var a = dashboard.getParameterValue("myParameter");
    if( a == "someValue"){
        this.chartDefinition.dataSource = "someQuery";
    }else{
        this.chartDefinition.dataSource = "someOtherQuery";
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: how can i change this property? can you give me some example please?